# Changing the Currency Symbol in Pentaho

Tags: pentaho

I created an anlysis report in pentaho user console. I had some revenue and profit measurements in the data set. So I need to add the currency symbol to those values. But in pentaho I can only add $ mark. How can I change to other currency symbols as I am interest in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Analyzer Reports simply you can change the currency symbol by editing the format of the field. Change the format of the field into currency and type the symbol you want.

- Click on the filed name.
- Select Column name and Format.
- Change the format to currency
- Type/ paste the currency symbol you want in the Symbol text box.
- Click OK.

Now it will change the currency type only for that report.

Or you can change the default currency symbol of the Analyzer report by following the below steps.

- Stop BA server
- Go to `...\server\biserver-ee\pentaho-solutions\system\analyzer`
- Edit analyzer.properties.
- Change `renderer.currency.symbol` attribute from `$` to desired currency.
- Save the changes.
- Re-start BA server.